# Pandas create dataframe from dict converting tuple to index

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a convenient way to implement a function `make_dataframe`, used as follows

```
mydict = {
    ('tom', 'gray') : [1,2,3,4,5],
    ('bill', 'ginger') : [6,7,8,9,10],
}

make_dataframe(mydict, tupleLabels=['catname', 'catcolor'], valueLabel='weight')
```

Expected result

```
| catname | catcolor | weight |
| tom | gray | 1 |
| tom | gray | 2 |
| tom | gray | 3 |
| tom | gray | 4 |
| tom | gray | 5 |
| bill | ginger | 6 |
| bill | ginger | 7 |
| bill | ginger | 8 |
| bill | ginger | 9 |
| bill | ginger | 10 |
```

It does not sound too difficult, I just don't want to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own function using dataframe **[`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)** after renaming the labels using **[`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)**:

```
def make_dataframe(dictionary , tupleLabels , valueLabel):
    return (pd.DataFrame(dictionary).rename_axis(tupleLabels,axis=1)
            .unstack().reset_index(tupleLabels,name=valueLabel))
```

---

```
out = make_dataframe(mydict, tupleLabels=['catname', 'catcolor'], valueLabel='weight')
```

---

```
print(out)

  catname catcolor  weight
0     tom     gray       1
1     tom     gray       2
2     tom     gray       3
3     tom     gray       4
4     tom     gray       5
0    bill   ginger       6
1    bill   ginger       7
2    bill   ginger       8
3    bill   ginger       9
4    bill   ginger      10
```

Comment: Fancy stuff. Thanks for showing me sth I did not know

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary is misformatted for easy conversion to a Pandas DataFrame.

I suggest doing the following:

```py
mydict = {
    ('tom', 'gray') : [1,2,3,4,5],
    ('bill', 'ginger') : [6,7,8,9,10],
}

l = [ [ k[0], k[1], val ] for k, v in mydict.items() for val in v ]

df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['catname', 'catcolor', 'weight'])
```

Which yields:

```
  catname catcolor  weight
0     tom     gray       1
1     tom     gray       2
2     tom     gray       3
3     tom     gray       4
4     tom     gray       5
5    bill   ginger       6
6    bill   ginger       7
7    bill   ginger       8
8    bill   ginger       9
9    bill   ginger      10
```

Comment: This most certainly is a possible solution, but it is exactly the thing I was trying to avoid. Looping over values in val can get expensive for larger problems. Hopefully pandas does the loop in C under the hood